# Why would Pedro Pascal not like the use of the term "baby Yoda"?

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes, the-mandalorian

I ran across [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx47W.jpg) where Pedro Pascal (the actor who plays The Mandalorian) says this

> GRAHAM NORTON: A lot of things are green screen but baby Yoda IS there?
> PEDRO PASCAL: Yes, baby Yoda is there. There's two different versions of... I can't believe I said baby Yoda.
> NORTON: Were you not supposed to say that?
> PASCAL: That's the first time.
> NORTON: The people from Disney are waiting for you.
> PASCAL: I gotta go

Considering that basically everyone calls [Grogu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grogu) "baby Yoda" (the character had no name until Episode 11/S2E5 [The Jedi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapter_13:_The_Jedi)) there's no confusion to be had there (especially since Norton himself calls him "baby Yoda"). Why would Pascal (or presumably Disney) not like the use of that term?

Comment: Because it's in bad taste and sounds like treating a child of his character like he was a toy plushy from a shop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Baby Yoda" is the unofficial fan nickname. "[The Child](https://www.ign.com/articles/mandalorian-baby-yoda-real-name-grogu-the-child)" is how he was referred to in Disney marketing. Essentially, Pedro used an unofficial term in an official interview.

Comment: What's more, Disney stuck to this term in official merch even when "Baby Yoda" would have made much better copy: https://www.shopdisney.com/the-child-on-board-car-magnet-star-wars-the-mandalorian-474099900259.html

Comment: Because "Baby Yoda" is inaccurate.  He's NOT Yoda.  He's a child of the same long-lived species as Yoda.  It would be like calling every human infant you see "baby Frank" just because Frank is an adult human that you're really fond of.  Or calling every Rodian infant "baby Greedo", or calling Ahsoka Tano "teenage Shaak Ti" just because they're both Togruta.

Comment: They're not only long lived, but apparently very powerful in the Force...advantages for which they sacrificed a lot of language skills...

Comment: Does this mean I should stop calling Luke "Baby Vader"?

Comment: @CaptAlgorithm Except it was the most accurate and efficient way to refer to this character who had no name and and no species name given to it.  "The Child" was much to generic to be useful.  For myself, I blurted out "It's a child Yoda!" at the end of the first episode and, I assume, the **vast** majority of viewers had a similar response.  "Yoda" was the natural way to identify the character's species, and "Baby" was the natural way to identify the apparent age.  By the time the powers-that-be saw fit to give an official name (a YEAR later), it was much too late.

Comment: Frankly, I don't see any real issue with people having used "Baby Yoda" as the term. :-D But, well, that was not the official term. Which is likely why Pedro was troubled at his blunder.

Comment: @sf02 You are supposed to call him ‘baby Ani’.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson accurate?  no, for the reasons I state.  But those are all reasons why the great unwashed masses of the VIEWERSHIP might use the term "Baby Yoda".  Presumably, Pedro was aware of "The Child" appellation during filming, or at least as prep for the press junkets.  He had information you did not:  a script and Disney looking over his shoulder.  Notably, not once does his character, who also had no disclosed name for a while, call Grogu "baby Yoda".  And no, calling him "Mando" or "Mandalorian" is not the same.  Calling him "Fake Boba Fett" would be more equivalent.

Comment: The key issue here is that we don't know the name of the species Yoda and Grogu belong to. Since Yoda was the only known member of that species shown in Star Wars for a long time (until a Vandar Tokare and Yaddle), it's fair to reference him when seeing other members of that species. In fact, Wookiepedia still refers to the species as, [Yoda's Species](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yoda%27s_species) (although it is flagged as having a conjectural name).